# Db image format for CardFiveID Printing Software

Tags: sql-server, image, integration

I`m using Card Five ID Printing Software for ID Card Printers. It is card design software, and I want to print cards with data that is stored
in MSSQL Server database. The problem is with storing photos of employees. I tried different formats JPG, BMP and I used binary reader from C# to populate image filed in my database.

I would apreciate if anyone have some idea how to solve this problem , and what format of data, Card Five software is using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to their website, Card Five supports (at least) JPEG images.

How are you storing the images? To store files before FILESTREAM came along, we used a varbinary(max) field and wrote a simple C# front-end to take the stream and save it (or open it) based on the MIME type (which we stored in the table with the data). While MIME did add a small bit of overhead, it was much easier to work with the data.